# Azure Devops- How to add if-else condition in the script

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to execute the pytest in the main pipeline from another pytest template yaml

```
# test-template.yml

parameters:
- name: jobName
  type: string

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
    inputs:
      versionSpec: some_python_version
      script: |
        if [ "${{ parameters.jobName }}" = "Pytest1" ]; then
          pytest -v tests -k "pretest_case1"
        elif [ "${{ parameters.jobName }}" = "Pytest2" ]; then
          pytest -v tests -k "postTest_case2"
        else
          # Handle any other jobName value or add an error message if needed.
          echo "Invalid jobName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}"
          exit 1
        fi
```

### Main.yaml

```
trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: test_int1
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu'
  jobs:
    - template: test-template.yml
      parameters:
        jobName: 'Pytest1'

- stage: test_int2
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu'
  jobs:
    - template: test-template.yml
      parameters:
        jobName: 'Pytest2'
```

but while testing this pipeline, it throw error says

"The directive if is not allowed in the context. Directives are not suppossed for expression that are embedded within string"

Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

`UsePythonVersion` doesn't have [input script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-python-version-v0?view=azure-pipelines)

```
# Use Python version v0
# Use the specified version of Python from the tool cache, optionally adding it to the PATH.
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x' # string. Required. Version spec. Default: 3.x.
    #disableDownloadFromRegistry: false # boolean. Disable downloading releases from the GitHub registry. Default: false.
    #allowUnstable: false # boolean. Optional. Use when disableDownloadFromRegistry = false. Allow downloading unstable releases. Default: false.
    #githubToken: # string. Optional. Use when disableDownloadFromRegistry = false. GitHub token for GitHub Actions python registry. 
    #addToPath: true # boolean. Add to PATH. Default: true.
  # Advanced
    architecture: 'x64' # 'x86' | 'x64'. Required. Architecture. Default: x64.
```

For this you should use `PythonScript`

```
# Python script v0
# Run a Python file or inline script.
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath' # 'filePath' | 'inline'. Required. Script source. Default: filePath.
    scriptPath: # string. Required when scriptSource = filePath. Script path. 
    #script: # string. Required when scriptSource = inline. Script. 
    #arguments: # string. Arguments. 
  # Advanced
    #pythonInterpreter: # string. Python interpreter. 
    #workingDirectory: # string. Working directory. 
    #failOnStderr: false # boolean. Fail on standard error. Default: false.
```

You can try something like this

```
# test-template.yml

parameters:
- name: jobName
  type: string

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
    inputs:
      versionSpec: some_python_version
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest1') }}:
    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline' 
        script: pytest -v tests -k "pretest_case1"
  - ${{ elseif eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest2') }}:
    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline' 
        script: pytest -v tests -k "postTest_case2"
  - ${{ else }}:
    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline' 
        script: |
          echo "Invalid jobName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}"
          exit 1
```

Comment: Is this should be part of script right?
"versionSpec: some_python_version
  ${{ if eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest1') }"

Comment: the above code throwing syntax error saying unclosed function 'eq' located at position 1 within expression

Comment: @Hari i fixed syntax

Comment: Thanks  Krzysztof Madej. now i am getting syntax error on 
"pytest -v tests -k "pretest_case1"
says syntax error on '-k'. But as tried with running without '-k',ie- "pytest -v tests", still i am getting the syntax error.. not sure what causes the error on script side?

Comment: looks like PythonScript@0 not supported for running those script?

Comment: Could you try this syntax `pytest -v -k "postTest_case2" tests`? Can you share error message if you get one?